# Magento Change Product name added to cart

Tags: product, price, name

i want to change product name to custom name when added to cart:

i wrote below code to change price ,but unable to change product name why so ,what to do for that

```
<checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    <observers>
        <setadiscountprice>
            <class>Mour_Customgroup_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>modifyPrice</method>
        </setadiscountprice>
    </observers>
</checkout_cart_product_add_after>
```

observer

```
public function modifyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $obs ){

    $item = $obs->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
    $product_id=$item->getProductId();
    $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    $price=$_product->getPrice();

    $specialPrice = $price+10;

    // Make sure we don't have a negative
    if ($specialPrice > 0) {
        $item->setCustomPrice($specialPrice);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($specialPrice);
        $item->setName('helllloo');
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: you want to change particular product name only or for all

Comment: Please try with `$item->getProduct()->setName('helllloo');`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that inside the cart `checkout/cart/render/simple.phtml` the default to get the name is:

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName()) ?>
```

And this gets the name from the product, rather then from the item.

```
public function getProductName()
{
    if ($this->hasProductName()) {
        return $this->getData('product_name');
    }
    return $this->getProduct()->getName();
}
```

So you need to change this to `$_item->getName()` then you get the set name.

Answer (score 1):

Why change the name of the product on cart add? Just add a secondary product attribute and then display *that* in the cart item render rather than the product name.

Comment: And review step and order item renderer and invoice item renderer and credit memo item renderer and email templates and PDFs... I think changing the item name is actually simpler ;)

Comment: Wonderfully thought out Fabian :)